# UmbrellaException when accessing variable type List<File> (lib-gwt-file & GWT)

Tags: java, exception, gwt, file-upload, runtime-error

I get this error in browser log:

```
Uncaught com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'add_75_g$' of undefined
    castFireEventFromSource_0_g$ @ EventBus.java:77
    fireEventFromSource_2_g$ @ SimpleEventBus.java:67
    fireEvent_9_g$ @ DropPanel.java:97
    fireNativeEvent_1_g$ @ DomEvent.java:125
    dispatch_87_g$ @ DropPanel.java:125
    handler_0_g$ @ DropPanel.java:87
```

This exception raises when I try to use List<File> any way. Using any other variable type just works which makes me suspect this might not be my fault. But I'm too inexperienced to be sure.

```
import org.vectomatic.file.File;
import org.vectomatic.file.FileList;

protected List<File> readQueue;
protected File fileHolder;

private void processFiles(FileList files)
{
  for(File file : files)
  {
        GWT.log(file.getName());

        fileHolder = file; // No error
        readQueue.add(file); // Error
    }
}
```

Even accessing `readQueue.size();` raises this exception.

I'm using GWT-2.7.0 and lib-gwt-file 0.3.6.
According to http://www.vectomatic.org/libs/lib-gwt-file these are correct versions to work together.

Code compiles without errors.

I'm stuck, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.. I didn't use:

```
protected List<File> readQueue = new ArrayList<File>();
```

For my defense... example code did not use one either.